# Execute this command line in Windows

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, expo, windows-terminal

I'm trying to connect my **firebase** auth to an **expo** project.
I'm following the main docs of each library. I'm stucking on [this step](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/).

I'm not able in windows to exeute this command line `openssl rand -base64 32 | openssl sha1 -c`.
I've tried with the specific https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads but I don't know how to reproduce the same line.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install openssl. It is usually available on Linux (which I think that article might have been written for).  There are some Windows binaries available at [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Binaries). Alternatively, you could setup a WSL session, and run the command from there.

Answer (score 0):

that is a linux command. Therefore a linux terminal is needed.

there are at least 2 ways to get this done

1. using virtual machine with ubuntu or some other operating system that uses a linux terminal aka shell (which I doubt you know about)

OR

2. installing a linux emulator (windows 8+ since it's from the windows store)

assuming you would prefer option 2, go to the windows store, search "Kali" and you will find an app called Kali. install it and if an error shows up, here's a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mR9XYoEFOoo) here that talks about solving that error and you would have a kali terminal on your windows computer (your command would work there)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it cover my needs. I wasn't able to find kali in windows 8+ store but I've just find out the installer from their site...